# Splash Screen for Android Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, splash-screen

I have a WebView app and would like to add a splash screen to show either while loading the page, or for a set amount of time. I have tried some other solutions but could not find one that worked. If necessary to know, my splash image is splash.png, located in the drawable folder.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Tap Twice To Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    } else {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

    }
}
public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfos != null)
            if(netInfos.isConnected())
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW,
            "MLINKS",
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),

            Uri.parse("android-app://PACKAGE-NAME/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW,
            "MLINKS",
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            Uri.parse("android-app://PACKAGE-NAME/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: what are you trying to do ? your question is not too clear

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I want to show a splash screen rather than the webview, until the page finishes loading.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Define a Progress Dialog:

```
    private ProgressDialog pd;
```

Then inside your:

view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser() {

Insert this:

```
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Im pretty new to Android Studio and do not know how to do this, could you give any links or code on how to do this?

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this at one time.  IIRC, it went like this:

First, I created a special `ImageView` subclass that overrode `onTouchEvent()` and threw away all the events.

Then for my layout, I had my `ImageView` subclass overlay the `WebView` then made it hidden, like this (for example):

```
<FrameLayout
    ...
    >

    <WebView
        ...
        />

    <com.example.TouchHandlerImageView
        ....
        android:src="R.drawable.splash"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />  
....
</FrameLayout>
```

Then my code went like this:

- Show the splash imageview. (The `onTouchEvent()` would keep touch events from going through to the `WebView` underneath)
- Start the page loading (In my case, I also had to run some javascript to set up the page)
- In `WebViewClient` `onPageFinshed()`, hide the splash imageview, displaying the `WebView` with page fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

at first thing make a background and show it im main screen till the data is being ready.

use  [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Class because it has 3 methods which them

1- onPreExecute() //don't do anything here

2- doInBackgroundProcess()// fetch your data here

3- onPostExecute()//get back the original background